# Return types with templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm in the process of re-writing a project originally written in C# into C++ as part of my assignment. While C# provides a convenient `.Length` method to determine the size of arrays, C++ lacks a direct equivalent, so I've had to create my own helper functions to retrieve the size of a "`readonly`"(invariant) array in C++.

To ensure code reusability, I've created a template function following C++ best practices, but I encountered an issue because I initially bound it to a return value type, which limited its flexibility. Specifically, I wanted to keep this template function reusable across different scenarios, not just ones where it returns a `size_t`.

```
//this works fine and returns size_t
template<typename T>
using EnableIFIntegralOrString = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, size_t>::type;                

template<typename T>
EnableIFIntegralOrString<T> ResourceConversion::Formula::ArraySize(const T* Array) const {
    if(Array == nullptr)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("[Array == {nullptr}]");
    }
    
    size_t Size = 0;
    for (const T* ptr = Array; *ptr != std::end(Array); ++ptr) {
        ++Size;
    }
    return Size;
}
```

I want to re-use the template in the following case, but I want to return a `bool` instead of `size_t`

```
//want to return a bool
template<typename T>
EnableIFIntegralOrString<T> ResourceConversion::Formula::ContainsNullOrWhitespace(const T* Array)
{
    if(Array == nullptr)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("[Array == {nullptr}]");
    }
    
    for(const std::string* ptr = Array; ptr != std::end(Array); ++ptr)
    {
        if(ptr -> empty() || std::all_of(ptr -> begin(), ptr -> end(), ::isspace))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The only solution I can think of is swapping `size_t` with `std::any`, but would prefer not to do that if by any means possible.

Comment: `for(const std::string* ptr = Array; ptr != nullptr; ++ptr)` will this loop ever end?

Comment: @billz Good point, probably not. It should be `end(Array)`.

Comment: *"I've created a template function following C++ best practices"* - it's exactly opposite almost in every aspect. Careless wandering among raw pointers is never a good idea, given that type of `T` is constraint to be `int` or `string` condition `*ptr != nullptr` makes no sense, there is actually a standard function `std::size` to obtain array size, etc. As for template itself, return type should probably be declared as `auto` to be deduced while `EnableIFIntegralOrString` should be put inside of `static_assert`.

Comment: I am not a fan of raw pointers either and would prefer to use containers "every day of the week". I am limited in what I can and cannot use, and this week, pointers are on the menu.

Comment: @user7860670 I was unaware of `std::size` so thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` ? It has a `size()` method as well as other advantages.

Comment: @wohlstad It's an assignment, and I can't use STL containers, unfortunately.

Comment: @user7860670 I get an error saying `auto` is not allowed in template arguments. Did I misinterpret your comment, or could it be because I am compiling with C++11?

Comment: I guess, if you feel like it, you could tell your professor that learning a language (C++) without being allowed to use the language (STL containers) makes little sense.

Comment: Does `std::end(Array)` even compile?

Comment: Another note, what is `std::end(Array)` supposed to return if `Array` is of type `const T*`? What is the 'end' of a pointer?

Comment: `auto` as a return type was introduced in C++14. I've assumed you are using C++20. If question targets some specific language version then you should've added an appropriate tag, such as `c++11`.

Comment: Simply put, there is _no way_ to determine the length of an array from a raw pointer to its first element (unless you add constraints, like ending with some sentinel value).  You need to track the length separately and pass it around.  If you cannot use a standard container that does that for you, write your own class that holds a pointer and a size.